# How to vectorized a bunch of documents in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark. I have a bunch of text documents of would like to convert them into sparse TF vectorized docment. That is, I'd like to generate a matrix which columns shows the words (terms) and the rows depict the document and each element is the term frequency of the term (shown by column) within a document (shown by row). I noticed that the class `TFHashing` does such a thing, how ever I don't know how to use it.

I'd like to pass a folder containing all my text document and get a file containing the sparse matrix. Besides, does Spark support any sort of n-grams? I means to tokenized the terms using 2-grams or 3-grams for example?

Apache Mahout has a powerful tool called `seq2sparse` which does all those task I mentioned and I'm looking for something similar in Spark.

I need to pass the output of the vectorization to the LDA which is very recently released.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [example provided by Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/ml/simple_text_classification_pipeline.py).